# Wrap OS's user account management?

Tags: uac, reusability, user-accounts, service-accounts

Take a coffee machine that remembers user's preferences.  Some users can only *use* the machine, others can configure it, still others can upgrade the software...

The first idea to implement these 'user-specific' settings and privileges would be to start creating a `User` class, a `Privilege` class, assigning privileges to certain actions, ...

But is that a good idea?

Would it be possible to reuse the OS's user account system to accomplish this?

If so, would it be a good idea?

Comment: Erm, I don't understand what your problem is. You want to run commands with the system account regardless of which user is logged in?

Comment: No, I want 'a system' that authenticates users and that can authorize their actions based on their 'clearance' level.

Comment: In which language you are trying to do this? Maybe it's not possible to get the user name.

Comment: I am willing to abandon all languages that don't allow inyeraction with the os.

Comment: It's possible to save the OS-User (in Windows better the user id, because Usernames are not unique) with his rights. If you use an Active Directory/LDAP, you are able to use the groups the user is in to determine which rights are set for this user. You can then write a RuleEngine, which adds the Permission to the user dependent on it's groups for example.